# React js pushing new object to array always replace last object instead of insert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am having message listing, and appending live message received from socket, one object inserted from socket, but after that it always replace the last one instead of insert new.

```
const [chatList, setChatList] = useState(props.chatList ? props.chatList : []);

useEffect(() => {

    const messageListener = (message) => {
        console.log('message',message);
        console.log('chatList',chatList);

        if(message.conversation_id == props.conversation_id){

                const updatedMsgs = [...chatList,message];
                setChatList(updatedMsgs);
        }
        
    };
  
    socket.on('myEventName', messageListener);

    return () => {
      socket.off('myEventName', messageListener);
    };
  }, [props.conversation_id]);
```

New message and Messagelist log look like
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a stale enclosure of the `chatList` state. Use a functional state update to update from the previous state and not the state value closed over in callback scope, `setChatList(list => [...list, message]);`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const messageListener = (message) => {
    console.log('message',message);
    console.log('chatList',chatList);

    if (message.conversation_id == props.conversation_id) {
      setChatList(list => [...list, message]);
    } 
  };

  socket.on('myEventName', messageListener);

  return () => {
    socket.off('myEventName', messageListener);
  };
}, [props.conversation_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue does occurs due to the `Stale Closures` in Javascript.

> Hooks heavily rely on JavaScript [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). That's why hooks are so expressive and simple. But closures are sometimes tricky.

Here is the example:

```js
function DelayedCount() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  function handleClickAsync() {
    setTimeout(function delay() {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={handleClickAsync}>Increase async</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you quickly click the button 2 times, then it increase the count by 1 only, instead of 2.

On each click `setTimeout(delay, 1000)` schedules the execution of `delay()` after 1 second. `delay()` captures the variable `count` as being 0.

Both `delay() closures` (because 2 clicks have been made) update the state to the same value: `setCount(count + 1) = setCount(0 + 1) = setCount(1)`.

All because the `delay() closure` of the second click has captured the outdated count variable as being 0.

To fix the problem, We need to use a functional way `setCount(count => count + 1)` to update count state:

```js
...
function handleClickAsync() {
  setTimeout(function delay() {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, 1000);
}
...
```

Now the button does work as expected.

Here is the complete article which may help you to understand about `Stale Closures`. **[Article Link](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)**